# AsyncFileUpload doesn't work with jQuery.Load()

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, asyncfileupload

I created an ASPX page that I'd like to load dynamically and inject into a container. When I navigate to this page directly the upload works just fine. However when I'm using jQuery.Load() function to inject the content of the page the AsyncFileUpload control doesn't seem to do anything. What am I missing?

Comment: jquery and ajax controls do not work properly with each other. Could you share some code snippets